# In the given figure, $D$ is the mid point of..

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $D$ is the mid point of $BC$ and $AE:EB=3:1$, $AF:FC=2:1$ then find $EO:OF$.

[image]

Here, $O$ is the point of intersection of $AD$ and $EF$.

My attempt :

I tried by joining $BO$ and $CO$ and also by using the concept that the centroid divides the median in the ratio of $2:1$, but didn't get any idea.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using vectors?

Comment: @David Quinn, No. I didn't get the idea to start with vector.

Comment: @David Quinn,  Actually I am required to solve it using vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Menelaus' Theorem to get the ratio $\frac{EO}{FO}$. Let $EF$ and $BC$ intersect at $G$. Applying the Menelaus' Theorem on $\triangle ABC$ and line $F-E-G$ we get:

$$\frac{CG}{BG} = \frac{FC}{AF} \cdot \frac{EA}{BE} = \frac{3}{2}$$

From this:

$$\frac{BG}{CG} = \frac 23 \implies \frac{BC}{CG} = \frac 13 \implies \frac{DC}{CG} = \frac 16 \implies \frac{CG}{DC} = 6 \implies \frac{GD}{DC} = \frac{GD}{DB} = 5$$

Now applying Menelaus' Theorem on $\triangle GFC$ and line $A-O-D$ we get:

$$\frac{GO}{OF} = \frac{CA}{AF} \cdot \frac{DG}{CD} = \frac 32 \cdot 5 = \frac {15}2$$

Now apply Menelaus' Theorem on $\triangle GEB$ and line $A-O-D$ to get:

$$\frac{GO}{EO} = \frac{BA}{EA} \cdot \frac{GD}{BD} = \frac 43 \cdot 5 = \frac{20}3$$

From all this:

$$\frac{EO}{FO} = \frac{EO}{GO} \cdot \frac{GO}{FO} = \frac 3{20} \cdot \frac{15}{2} = \frac 98$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint as to how to proceed.

Let $\overrightarrow{AB}=a$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}=b$

Then $\overrightarrow{AE}=\frac 34a$ and $\overrightarrow{AF}=\frac 23b$

Now write down an expression for $\overrightarrow{EF}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Let $\overrightarrow{EO}=\lambda \overrightarrow{EF}$

Now write down an expression for $\overrightarrow{AO}$ in terms of $\lambda$, $a$ and $b$

Since $\overrightarrow{AO}=k(a+b)$ you can make an equation and equate the coefficients of $a$ To make one equation, and the coefficients of $b$, to make another equation, since they are independent, and thus obtain, by eliminating $k$ the value of $\lambda$.

You should get $\lambda=\frac{9}{17}$ and the required ratio is then $9:8$

I hope this helps